# Convert query to only use table once

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
select field1,field2 from
#table1 left join
(select field3, max (field4) as field2
from #table1
group by field3) a on #table1.field3 = a.field3
```

I want to change it so #table1 is only used once (and preferably the most efficient way also)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Think about how you can answer the query using the table just once.  If you can't think of such a procedure, maybe there isn't one.  Given the nature of the query, I think there isn't a way to avoid using the table twice - you need to join a summary of the table with the original data; you need to process the table twice.  Is there anything that makes you think it can be done so that the table is only used once?

Comment: last line: a.site_id isn't defined. Should it be field3?

Comment: @john - I didn't i could be done with only using the table once. which is why I wrote it that way. But #table is a temp table and I don't wannt use a temp table, but if i elimiate the temp table then I have call the temp table's definition in a subquery twice, which I don't wanna do, hence why i'm asking people more intelegent than I am if they have any ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT field1, MAX(field4) OVER (PARTITION BY field3) AS field2
FROM  #table1
```

Though following clarification in the comments...

> I think what i really was looking for
>   was one record per field3,  the
>   max(field4) and the corresponding
>   field1. And I think the assumption 
>   would have to be made that field1 and
>   field3 has a strictly one-many
>   relationship (aka a value of field3
>   could never have two corresponding
>   values of field1)

... I think this is what you actually need.

```
WITH cte As
(
SELECT field1, field3,field4,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field3 ORDER BY field4 DESC) AS RN
FROM #table1
)
SELECT  field1, field3,field4
FROM cte
WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: Thanks! So this should give me a row for every unique value of field3 right? What would happen in the case that one value of field3 matched up to two values of field1?

Comment: I think, to answer my own question, you would get two rows, because the only thing that determines the rows is field3.

Comment: This should do exactly the same as your example query. It will return all rows in `#table1` (you have a left join). For each row it will return the maximum value of `field4` corresponding to that rows `field3` value and it will alias that result as `field2`

Comment: WOW - so 2 things. First, thanks so much because that deff answered my question. Second, thanks so much because you just made me double think what I was doing and realize that my original query was wrong...

Comment: I think what i really was looking for was one record per field3, the max(field4) and the corrisponding field1. And I think the assumption would have to be made that field1 and field3 has a strictly one-many relationship(aka a value of field3 could never have two corrisponding values of field1)

Comment: So maybe something like Select distinct field1,field3,Max(field4) Over (Partition by field3) as field2 from #table1